# Missing segments in 999 file generated by BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, edi, x12

I have a query related to the 999 ack file being created when an 820 EDI message gets processed in one of the BizTalk applications in my org.

The generated 999 file does contain a code R for the AK9 segment which means the file has been rejected. However it does not contain the IK3 and IK4 segments which would have given more details about the reasons for the rejection of the file.

Have you experienced this scenario? If yes could you please share your understanding?

Comment: Both IK3 and IK4 are situational segment so it is OK to not generate them in a valid 999 file.  have you checked the AK905 element in your 999? It may reveal some information for you to troubleshoot your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BizTalk will definitely not generate IK3 or IK4 segments if there's a terminal error with the file, such as an error in the functional group (GS/GE) or sometimes even an error in the ST/SE pair(s).

The TR3 specifies that IK3 and IK4 should be sent "if the sender knows" what segments/elements were in error.  So even if there are no errors at the functional or transaction set enveloping levels, it's possible that the errors are just not trackable properly by the EDI Disassembler and it doesn't report them.

If you'd like to add these in for certain scenarios where your partner expects them (despite what the TR3 says), you'd have to do some custom work to capture the 999 and modify it.

Comment: Thanks Dan, your explanation is definitely helpful. I had the namespace of the schema typed incorrectly in the agreement settings and hence the incoming 820 was getting rejected. I had overlooked that earlier but once it was corrected, the files got accepted and the 999 had an acceptance code.